# BitmapData.getColorBoundsRect howto get inscribed rectangle, not bounds

Tags: actionscript-3

It is possible to get inscribed rectangle for transparent hole inside BitmapData object?
I mean green rectangle, not red. Here's a sketch:

[image]

Comment: How exactly is that inner rectangle defined? I mean, you could draw any number of arbitrary rectangles inside the transparant hole, what conditions does the rectangle need to fulfill?

Comment: I see now. No conditions :(